# passing parent id into hash for options for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hash

I have a method which takes two columns from the DELIVERYCOST database and groups the column `'title'` under grouping `'timing'`. It turns it into a hash

```
  def self.titles_by_timing
    self.pluck(:id, :timing, :title).group_by(&:first).each { |_, v| v.map!(&:last) }
  end

DeliveryCost.titles_by_timing
=> {"Install"=>["Luton Day (7am - 7pm)", "LWB Day (7am - 7pm)", "Luton Overtime (7pm - 7am)", "LWB Overtime", "Helper Day (7am - 7pm)", "Helper Overtime"], "Breakdown"=>["Luton Day (7am - 7pm)", "LWB Overtime", "Luton Overtime (7pm - 7am)", "Helper Day (7am - 7pm)", "Helper Overtime"], "Fuel"=>["Congestion Charge", "Fuel in London Zone 1-2", "Fuel in London Zone 3-4", "Fuel By Milege (Out of M25)]}
```

This is the section from the form for JOB DELIVERY COSTS

```
= f.select :delivery_cost_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(DeliveryCost.titles_by_timing, :timing, :title, :id)
```

Because JOB DELIVERY COSTS belongs to Delivery Costs, and Delivery costs has many Job delivery costs, I need to pass the id so as to create the association when creating an instance of job delivery cost. However I am having great difficulty in doing so. How do I do this, do I expand on my current method?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `DeliveryCost.titles_by_timing` is already doing all the heavy-lifting, so you should be using `grouped_options_for_select` instead of `option_groups_from_collection_for_select`.

Check [ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper#grouped_options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_options_for_select).

**UPDATE:**

Try using the following with `grouped_options_for_select`:

```rb
def self.titles_by_timing
  self.all.each_with_object(Hash.new([])) do |delivery_cost, grouped|
    grouped[delivery_cost.title] |= [[delivery_cost.id, delivery_cost.timing]]
  end
end
```

Be aware that this method may perform poorly due to loading all objects into memory. Should that be a problem, you could try some caching, memoization or delegating the expensive queries to the database.

Comment: yeah but i cant pass the id?!

Comment: You're right, my bad. I've updated the answer with a possible solution. Let me knows it that helps.